# Custom checkbox image android

Tags: android, checkbox

Is there an easy way to use a custom image for a checkbox? I'm looking to duplicate the "starred" behavior of gmail. So I want to have a checkbox that, when checked, is a filled in star. And when unchecked is an empty star. Do I have to use an imageview and do my own logic myself?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Checkboxes being children of Button you can just give your checkbox a background image with several states as described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html), under "Button style":

...and exemplified [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList):

Comment: Thanks, I actually found exactly what I needed here http://it-ride.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-android-favorite-button-right.html but I would have had to do it your way if I wanted a __real__ custom image =P

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I've been looking for - I've figured out the whole state thing but I've been setting android:background instead of android:button and ended up with 2 buttons instead. Now it all works well.

Comment: -1. The `android:button` solution below is much better than using background attribute !

Comment: @Orabîg: This downvote is wrong. The question is perfectly answered ("Custom checkbox image"). The fact that a shortcut exists for this particular starred-button does not invalidate this answer.

Comment: While this maybe an old post, would like to add that Android studio also uses the android:button="@android:drawable/btn_star" method

Comment: How to give ``width`` and ``height`` to the bitmap in the selector once you specify ``android:button``?

Comment: Note that if you use the `button` attribute, it will not scale a background image. If you use a `background` attribute instead, and set `android:button=@null`, your background will scale to the size of the checkbox

Comment: adding bare links is discouraged, please elaborate

Answer (score 316):

Create a drawable checkbox selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox" 
          android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkboxselected" 
          android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox"/>    
</selector>
```

Make sure your checkbox is like this `android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"`

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/Black" />
```

Comment: What record do you specify this selector in? Within the XML file itself where you're specifying the CheckBox as well?

Comment: Tom: create your selector in drawable folder and checkbox in layout folder

Comment: I had to change ´button´ for ´background´ in the CheckBox

Comment: For padding see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037795/android-spacing-between-checkbox-and-text

Comment: What if I have many checkboxes with diff. images to show on checking/unchecking the checkbox? How can I pass a parameter to the xml file? Or is there a alternative? I know we can create a seperate checkbox_selector for each but is there a better way?

Comment: +1 for  android:button I wanted a custom background so I used      android:button="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: I have upgraded my project to android x after that I could not customize my checkbox as you said before api level 21 and android:button not works.

Comment: I tried this, and realized `<item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox"/>` this is not needed and also takes precedence over check state as true.

Comment: @MisaghAghakhani See my answer below for the solution to that

Answer (score 45):

Copy the btn_check.xml from android-sdk/platforms/android-#/data/res/drawable to your project's drawable folder and change the 'on' and 'off' image states to your custom images.

Then your xml will just need `android:button="@drawable/btn_check"`

```
<CheckBox
    android:button="@drawable/btn_check"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true" />
```

If you want to use different default android icons, you can use `android:button="@android:drawable/..."`

Comment: Bad advice. Icons may be changed from version to version and may disappear at all. If you really like the default icon, you can grab it from sources.

Comment: Are you saying referencing the default icons directly via "@android:drawable/..." is a bad idea, or this process entirely?

Comment: Example: reference to holo icons will crash your app on pre-honeycomb devices. It is really difficult to maintain and debug such troubles. So I usually copy not only xml but the images too to be hundreed percent sure the resources will be found. Also this is very important to ensure UI look the same on every device.

Answer (score 28):

res/drawable/day_selector.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/dayselectionunselected"
              android:state_checked="false"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/daysselectionselected"
              android:state_checked="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/dayselectionunselected"/>
    </selector>
```

res/layout/my_layout.xml

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/check"
    android:layout_width="39dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:background="@drawable/day_selector"
    android:button="@null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="S"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Comment: Some explanation would help new users understand how your code solves the issue.

Answer (score 6):

If you have Android open source code, you can find the styles definition under:
*src/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values*

```
<style name="Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:background">
        @android:drawable/btn_check_label_background
    </item>
    <item name="android:button">
        ?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple
    </item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on the Enselic and Rahul answers.

It works for me (before and after API 21):

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text=""
    android:gravity="center"

    android:background="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
    android:button="@null"
    app:buttonCompat="@null" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it -

```
package com;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class CheckBoxImageView extends ImageView implements View.OnClickListener {
    boolean checked;
    int defImageRes;
    int checkedImageRes;
    OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener;

    public CheckBoxImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attr, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attr, defStyle);
        init(attr, defStyle);
    }

    public CheckBoxImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
        init(attr, -1);
    }

    public CheckBoxImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
        setImageResource(checked ? checkedImageRes : defImageRes);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {
        TypedArray a = null;
        if (defStyle != -1)
            a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.CheckBoxImageView, defStyle, 0);
        else
            a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.CheckBoxImageView);
        defImageRes = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
        checkedImageRes = a.getResourceId(1, 0);
        checked = a.getBoolean(2, false);
        a.recycle();
        setImageResource(checked ? checkedImageRes : defImageRes);
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        checked = !checked;
        setImageResource(checked ? checkedImageRes : defImageRes);
        onCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged(this, checked);
    }

    public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener) {
        this.onCheckedChangeListener = onCheckedChangeListener;
    }

    public static interface OnCheckedChangeListener {
        void onCheckedChanged(View buttonView, boolean isChecked);
    }
}
```

Add this attrib -

```
<declare-styleable name="CheckBoxImageView">
        <attr name="default_img" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="checked_img" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="checked" format="boolean"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Use like -

```
 <com.adonta.ziva.consumer.wrapper.CheckBoxImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:checked_img="@drawable/check_box_checked"
        app:default_img="@drawable/check_box" />
```

It will fix all your porblems.

Comment: It's missing the `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` methods, I think the checked state would be lost on rotation

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) with null background and a custom button.

Bellow an example that includes a selector to the text color as well.

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/toggle_selector"
    android:background="@null"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@drawable/toggle_text"
    android:textOn="My on state"
    android:textOff="My off state" />
```

*toggle_selector.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/state_on" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/state_off" />

</selector>
```

*toggle_text.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@color/app_color" />

    <item
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using custom adapters than `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` are nessesury to make list items clickable while using checkbox.

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_fav"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_layout"/>
```

In *drawable>checkbox_layout.xml*

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/uncked_checkbox"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_checkbox"
        android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/uncked_checkbox"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use **androidx.appcompat:appcompat** and want a custom drawable (of type `selector` with `android:state_checked`) to work on old platform versions in addition to new platform versions, you need to use

```
    <CheckBox
        app:buttonCompat="@drawable/..."
```

instead of

```
    <CheckBox
        android:button="@drawable/..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding custom drawable in the android:button did not work for me in Material Checkbox `version-1.3.0` . I had to set `android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_selector"` instead and also set `android:button="@null"` . You can also add `android:drawablePadding` to make it look good. However, this makes the entire checkbox clickable (along with the text).

Answer (score 0):

All you need two drawable one for checked state and other for unchecked or default state. You can then create a background drawable selector(xml) and apply it as background to your checkbox. As mentioned below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_checked_24" />
    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_unchecked_24" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_unchecked_24"/>
</selector>
```

No your checkbox in xml should look like this.

```
<CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/check_box"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:button="@null"
      android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background_drawable"/>
```

Make sure you have maked the button attribute of checkbox to null.