# How to change the color of a CheckBox in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-checkbox

How do I change the default `CheckBox` color in Android?
By default the `CheckBox` color is green, and I want to change this color.
If it is not possible please tell me how to make a custom `CheckBox`?

Comment: Are you trying to change the font's color? Or the color of the actual box?

Comment: actual box color i change

Comment: Setting the `android:buttonTint="@color/mybrown"` is an easy way to change the box color.

Comment: @Shauvik it just working on material design :)

Comment: @shauvik it's better to use `app:buttonTint="@color/mybrown"` instead, this way it can work on API < 21

Comment: `app:buttonTint` is a good solution for API < 21, but you'll also need to use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox`

Comment: @shauvik easy for >= 21.. many things are easy for >= 21...

Answer (score 298, accepted):

If your `minSdkVersion` is 21+ use `android:buttonTint` attribute to update the color of a checkbox:

```
<CheckBox
  ...
  android:buttonTint="@color/tint_color" />
```

In projects that use AppCompat library and support Android versions below 21 you can use a compat version of the `buttonTint` attribute:

```
<CheckBox
  ...
  app:buttonTint="@color/tint_color" />
```

In this case if you want to subclass a `CheckBox` don't forget to use `AppCompatCheckBox` instead.

**PREVIOUS ANSWER:**

You can change `CheckBox`s drawable using `android:button="@drawable/your_check_drawable"` attribute.

Comment: You'd have to create your own drawable.  There's gotta be a more straight-forward way...

Comment: Changing buttonTint colour is a more straight forward way. We have to use the native elements instead customising it unnecessarily.

Comment: The value of `buttonTint` seems to override the `textColor` value. Any ideas how to work around this?

Answer (score 434):

You can change the color directly in XML. Use `buttonTint` for the box: *(as of API level 23)*

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:buttonTint="@color/CHECK_COLOR" />
```

You can also do this using `appCompatCheckbox v7` for older API levels:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    app:buttonTint="@color/COLOR_HERE" />
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! And don't forget to add _xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"_ to your main/parent layout

Comment: Not working for me using 'android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox'

Comment: This will automatically be used when you use CheckBox in your layouts. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.

Comment: How about setting 2 different colors for checked and unchecked states?

Answer (score 152):

you can set android theme of the checkbox to get the color you want in your styles.xml add :

```
<style name="checkBoxStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">CHECKEDHIGHLIGHTCOLOR</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">UNCHECKEDCOLOR</item>
</style>
```

then in your layout file :

```
<CheckBox
     android:theme="@style/checkBoxStyle"
     android:id="@+id/chooseItemCheckBox"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

unlike using `android:buttonTint="@color/CHECK_COLOR"` this method works under Api 23

Comment: TEXTCOLORSECONDARY!!!! THank you man! That's it. I searched for ages to just change the unselected background color and did not want to work with custom drawables. This is it!

Comment: @Mulgard glad I can help !

Comment: Worked for me, but needed to add to the CheckBox xml to be able to see the text - android:textColor="@color/textColor"

Comment: How do I do it also programmatically?

Comment: @Zvi I am not sure you can do this programatically

Comment: I used `app:buttonTint="@color/CHECK_COLOR"` instead of `android` prefix and it worked fine in my pre-lollipop device

Comment: @Zvi see my answer below for the programmatic version.

Comment: I never knew this was soo easy.

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Comment: Note: For material design styling, there is the `contentControl` options now: https://materialdoc.com/components/selection-controls/

Comment: How can I apply this `checkBoxStyle` globally?

Comment: I am trying to use this in React Native. Where should I place the <Checkbox /> field?

Comment: you should add padding to this style:
        <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>

Comment: Cleanest way by far!

Answer (score 81):

Use **`buttonTint`** to change color of button and color selector for above 21+ api version.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                android:id="@+id/check"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:buttonTint="@color/checkbox_filter_tint"
                tools:targetApi="21"/>
```

res/colors/checkbox_filter_tint.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/light_gray_checkbox"
          android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:color="@color/common_red"
          android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Can you speak English and explain your answer plse

Comment: Always stick with English in SO.

Comment: It is a better answer

Comment: This seems to be the only simple approach for setting both the checked and unchecked colors that works on all devices.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Although it should be noted that it doesnt work when the selector is declared as a `values` resource. As indicated by the path shown above, it has to be inside the `colors` resource folder.

Answer (score 58):

Programmatic version:

```
int [][] states = {{android.R.attr.state_checked}, {}};
int [] colors = {color_for_state_checked, color_for_state_normal}
CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(checkbox, new ColorStateList(states, colors));
```

Comment: Thanks to You. You rocks, The better solution.

Comment: it gave me unexpected result with colors, are you sure you didn't confuse anything?

Comment: @Carlos This is not a "better" solution, because in android you should always try to set all the layout stuff in the xml file and not programmatically except when you need to change it dynamically

Comment: @kyay Not "always" ... the Android resource system is a mess and often doing it programmatically is far easier and more maintainable.

Comment: It sort of helps separation of concerns

Comment: @kyay10 that's absolutely a wrong statement. If you think the opposite then take a look about what's happening with Jetpack Compose.

Answer (score 21):

I would suggest to use he style approach in android as the way to configure built-in android views, add new style in your project:

```
<style name="yourStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">your_color</item> <!-- for uncheck state -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">your color</item> <!-- for check state -->
</style>
```

and add assign this style to the theme of the checkbox:
 android:theme="@style/youStyle"

hope this helps.

Comment: agree with this solution, those attributes should work better with the default built-in android component without hassle on the drawable like the upvoted answer.

Comment: This is a repeat of Amro elaswar's answer from 9 months earlier.

Comment: This is the kind of solution that is A REAL SOLUTION.

Answer (score 20):

> Add buttonTint in your xml

```
<CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/chk_remember_signup"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:buttonTint="@android:color/white"
      android:text="@string/hint_chk_remember_me" />
```

Comment: The content of this answer already exists in [afathman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33834496/1813169).

Answer (score 11):

Add this line in your `styles.xml` file:

```xml
<style>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer with your example and don't post it as a comment

Comment: Slight correction: It's <item name="**android**:colorAccent></item>.
Also, this is only available from API 21 and up.

Comment: this changes the colorAccent, it's not what it was asked

Comment: On Galaxy S3 it changes only checked state of a CheckBox. But unchecked state is still the same.

Answer (score 8):

Me faced same problem, I got a solution using below technic. Copy the `btn_check.xml` from `android-sdk/platforms/android-#(version)/data/res/drawable` to your project's drawable folder and change the 'on' and 'off' image states to your custom images.
Then your xml will just need `android:button="@drawable/btn_check"`

```
<CheckBox
    android:button="@drawable/btn_check"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true" />
```

If you want to use different default Android icons, you can use:

```
android:button="@android:drawable/..."
```

Comment: Great answer - much easier than creating custom xml .. thanks!  For me, I have a gray background and the checkbox border was not visible.  I added this and you can see it now: android:button="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background"

Comment: There's actually a bit more to using this approach than I realized .. but still a nice option.  I have added details below http://stackoverflow.com/a/29831532/2162226

Answer (score 8):

buttonTint worked for me try

**android:buttonTint="@color/white"**

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/agreeCheckBox"
    android:text="@string/i_agree_to_terms_s"
    android:buttonTint="@color/white"
    android:layout_below="@+id/avoid_spam_text"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

create an xml `Drawable resource file` under `res->drawable` and name it, for example, `checkbox_custom_01.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
   android:state_checked="true"   
   android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_custom_01_checked_white_green_32" />
  <item 
   android:state_checked="false" 
   android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_custom_01_unchecked_gray_32" />
</selector>
```

Upload your custom checkbox image files (i recommend png) to your `res->drawable` folder.

Then go in your layout file and change your checkbox to

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_custom_01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:textSize="32dip"/>
```

you may customize anything, as long as `android:button` points to the correct XML file you created before.

NOTE TO NEWBIES: though it is not mandatory, it is nevertheless good practice to name your checkbox with a unique id throughout your whole layout tree.

Answer (score 5):

You can change `checkbox` color using singe line of code

`android:buttonTint="@color/app_color"     //whatever color`

Answer (score 5):

100% robust approach.

In my case, I didn't have access to the XML layout source file, since I get Checkbox from a 3-rd party MaterialDialog lib.
So I have to solve this programmatically.

1. Create a ColorStateList in xml:

res/color/*checkbox_tinit_dark_theme.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:color="@color/positiveButtonBg"
        android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

2. Then apply it to the checkbox:

   ```
   ColorStateList darkStateList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getContext(), R.color.checkbox_tint_dark_theme);
   CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(checkbox, darkStateList);
   ```

P.S. In addition if someone is interested, here is how you can get your checkbox from MaterialDialog dialog (if you set it with `.checkBoxPromptRes(...)`):

```
CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) dialog.getView().findViewById(R.id.md_promptCheckbox);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

There is a much easier way to set the color programmatically by setting `ColorStateList`.

```
 Checkbox.setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getContext().getColor(R.color.yourcolor)))
```

Answer (score 5):

If textColorSecondary does not work for you, you might have defined colorControlNormal in your theme to be a different color. If so, just use

```
<style name="yourStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">your_checked_color</item> <!-- for checked state -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">your_unchecked_color</item> <!-- for unchecked state -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

Most answers go through the xml file. If you find an active answer for most Android versions and are just one color for the two statuses Check an UnCheck: here is my solution:

Kotlin:

```
val colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.CYAN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
CompoundButtonCompat.getButtonDrawable(checkBox)?.colorFilter = colorFilter
```

Java:

```
ColorFilter colorFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.CYAN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
Drawable drawable = CompoundButtonCompat.getButtonDrawable(checkBox);
if (drawable != null) {
    drawable.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following two properties in "colors.xml"

```
<color name="colorControlNormal">#eeeeee</color>
<color name="colorControlActivated">#eeeeee</color>
```

colorControlNormal is for the normal view of checkbox, and colorControlActivated is for when the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 3):

Hi This is  the theme code for both Dark Theme and Light Theme.

```
<attr name="buttonsearch_picture" format="reference"/>
<attr name="buttonrefresh_picture" format="reference"/>

<style name="Theme.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/material_gray_800</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/LightOverflowButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonsearch_picture">@drawable/ic_search_black</item>
    <item name="buttonrefresh_picture">@drawable/ic_refresh_black</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/material_gray_500</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/material_gray_800</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/DarkOverflowButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonsearch_picture">@drawable/ic_search_white</item>
    <item name="buttonrefresh_picture">@drawable/ic_refresh_white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/LightDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/LightDialogTheme</item>
  <!-- <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.Widget.TextView</item>-->
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>
```

If you want to change checkbox color then "colorAccent" attribute will use for checked state and "android:textColorSecondary" will use for unchecking state.

"actionOverflowButtonStyle" will use for change the color of overflow icon in the Action bar.

"buttonsearch_picture" attribute will use for change tint color of Action Button in  Action Bar.This is custom Attribute in style.xml

```
<attr name="buttonsearch_picture" format="reference"/>
```

Same is for refresh button which i am using in my app.

"android:popupMenuStyle" attribute is using to get Light theme popup menu style in Dark theme.

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

And this is toolbar Code which I am using in my Rocks Player App.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:title="Rocks Player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Themes:-

```
 <style name="AppTheme0" parent="Theme.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#cccccc</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#0294ff</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.Dark">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#4161b2</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#4161b2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#4161b2</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

My **minSdkVersion** is `15`, my **BaseAppTheme** parent is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` and I am creating my Checkboxes programmatically. The following steps worked for me.

**1.** In your **Java** code, change

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(context);
```

to

```
AppCompatCheckBox checkBox = new AppCompatCheckBox(context);
```

**2.** In your **styles.xml**, add:

```
<style name="MyCheckboxStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="buttonTint">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

**3.** Finally, within your **BaseAppTheme** (or **AppTheme**) style, add:

```
<item name="checkboxStyle">@style/MyCheckboxStyle</item>
<item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/MyCheckboxStyle</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can create your own xml in drawable and use this as android:background="@drawable/your_xml"

in that you can give border corner everything

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient

            android:endColor="#fff"
            android:startColor="#fff"/>
        <corners
            android:radius="2dp"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="15dp"
            android:color="#0013669e"/>

    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Whilst it is noice to know about drawable vector graphics this answer does not answer the OP's question about the button tint.

Answer (score 2):

My goal was to use a custom checkbox button and **remove the accent color button tint**. I tried the accepted answer but did now work instead this worked for me:

In the `styles.xml` file

```
<style name="Theme.Checkbox" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/theme_checkbox_button</item>
    <item name="android:drawableLeft">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:buttonTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:buttonTintMode">screen</item>
</style>
```

**Now for this question, only required attributes are `android:buttonTint` and `android:buttonTintMode`**

Now some extras:

- I needed to use a custom drawable, hence `android:button` is set with a `selector` drawable
- I needed some spacing between the box and the text hence I followed [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19212135/13754639) and set the `android:drawableLeft` and `android:drawablePadding`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the background color of the `<CheckBox>` by embedding it inside a `<LinearLayout>`. Then change the background color of `<LinearLayout>` to the color you want.

Comment: The question is about the color of the checkbox and not the background

Answer (score 1):

You should try below code. It is working for me.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checked" 
          android:state_checked="true">
        <color android:color="@color/yello" />
    </item>
    <!-- checked -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" 
          android:state_checked="false">
        <color android:color="@color/black"></color>
    </item>
    <!-- unchecked -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checked" 
          android:state_focused="true">
        <color android:color="@color/yello"></color>
    </item>
    <!-- on focus -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked">
        <color android:color="@color/black"></color>
    </item>
    <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

and CheckBox

```
<CheckBox
    Button="@style/currentcy_check_box_style"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:text="@string/step_one_currency_aud" />
```

Comment: Where is `currentcy_check_box_style` defined in your `selector` or theme? Where do you place the `selector`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use the android icons, as described above ..

```
android:button="@android:drawable/..."
```

.. it's a nice option, but for this to work - I found you need to add toggle logic to show/hide the check mark, like this:

```
    checkBoxShowPwd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        // checkbox status is changed from uncheck to checked.
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            int btnDrawable = android.R.drawable.checkbox_off_background;

            if (isChecked)
            {
                btnDrawable = android.R.drawable.checkbox_on_background;
            }

            checkBoxShowPwd.setButtonDrawable(btnDrawable);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, this is extra work that really isn't necessary.  In the drawable's xml file you supply references to on or off drawable resources for the selector.  This automatically puts the correct drawable according to the checkbox's state.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this extension function I've created:

```
fun CheckBox.setTint(@ColorInt color: Int?) {
    if (color == null) {
        CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(this, null)
        return
    }
    CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintMode(this, Mode.SRC_ATOP)
    CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(this, ColorStateList.valueOf(color))
}
```

It's very similar to what I have for ImageView, in case anyone wants it too:

```
fun ImageView.setTint(@ColorInt color: Int?) {
    if (color == null) {
        ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(this, null)
        return
    }
    ImageViewCompat.setImageTintMode(this, Mode.SRC_ATOP)
    ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(this, ColorStateList.valueOf(color))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change tint color using ColorStateList.

```
fun CheckBox.tint(colors: ColorStateList) {
    buttonTintList = colors
}

fun CheckBox.tint(@ColorInt color: Int) = tint(context.colorStateList(color))
```

For other general material views.

```
fun SeekBar.tint(@ColorInt color: Int) {
    val s1 = ColorStateList.valueOf(color)
    thumbTintList = s1
    progressTintList = s1
}

fun ProgressBar.tint(@ColorInt color: Int, skipIndeterminate: Boolean = false) {
    val sl = ColorStateList.valueOf(color)
    progressTintList = sl
    secondaryProgressTintList = sl
    if (!skipIndeterminate) indeterminateTintList = sl
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, but if you want to use different colors for checked and unchecked state, you can use material check box instead of normal check box, and set buttonTint and buttonIconTint

```
        <com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:buttonIconTint="@color/black"
            app:buttonTint="@color/white" />
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the below lines of code to change the background of the Checkbox dynamically in your java code.

```
//Setting up background color on checkbox.
 checkbox.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00e2a5"));
```

This answer was from this [site](https://www.android-examples.com/set-background-color-for-checkbox-in-android-programmatically/). You can also use this [site](https://www.rgbtohex.net/) to convert your RGB color to the Hex value, you need to feed the parseColor