# Change style of checked checkbox in Option menu item

Tags: android, checkbox, menu

I am trying to create an Option Menu with checkboxes. However, for some reason, the checked checkboxes are white. Which makes them very hard to see on the light gray background. I don't know why they are white. The text and the unchecked checkboxes are dark gray. I've been trying to make them the same color as the unchecked boxes but couldn't figure out how. Here is a screenshot of them:

[image: Screenshot]

And this is what my `menu.xml` looks like:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <group
        android:checkableBehavior="all">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:title="@string/menuUseLocation"
            android:checked="true"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:title="@string/menuUseHypridMap"
            android:checked="false"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/vibration"
            android:title="@string/menuUseVibration"
            android:checked="true"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

I am using this theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And these colors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#da121a</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
    <color name="drawerBackground">#da121a</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#F4F4F4</color>
    <color name="background">#F4F4F4</color>
    <color name="text">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Any ideas about how to fix this problem?

Comment: Which  accent_color  you have used?

Comment: This answer might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854047/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-checkbox

Comment: @NitinKarande: I added my the Theme I am using and my `colors.xml`. You were right about the `colorAccent`. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your code snippets and screenshot . I will suggest to change your **acentColor**

ColorAccent will be display in your checkBox selected value in those you have given in accentColor in your style.

I hope it will work.