# How to change CheckBox color in Toolbar Menu Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to change the color of a checkbox but its not working. **How to change the color of checkbox after it's checked?** I'm applying a theme but its not working:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/tagsSelectAll_menu"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox"
    android:checkable="true"    
    android:theme="@style/WhiteCheck"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="SelectAll"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the color of a CheckBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854047/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem for you was to get the actual reference to the `Checkbox`. You can do that either through `onCreateOptionsMenu()` or `onOptionsItemSelected()` depending on your use case. Keep the reference to that `Checkbox` and update the color after some event.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.menu.your_menu_item);
    // `checkbox` is a field of the class
    checkbox = (Checkbox) item.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.my_checkbox);
}
```

[How to change the color of a CheckBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854047/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-checkbox)

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this,

    <item
     android:id="@+id/tagsSelectAll_menu"
     app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox"
     android:checkable="true"    
     android:theme="@style/WhiteCheck"
     app:showAsAction="always"
     android:background="@drawable/button_states"
     android:title="SelectAll"    
    />


button_states xml:-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="1000dp"/>
<solid android:color="#00000000"/>
<stroke android:color="#00000000" android:width="2dip"/>
<padding android:top="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:bottom="4dp"/>
</shape>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="1000dp"/>
<solid android:color="#00000000"/>
<stroke android:color="#00000000" android:width="2dip"/>
<padding android:top="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:bottom="4dp"/>
</shape>
</item>
</selector>
```