# Change the color of Checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, android-checkbox

I want to change the color of checkbox border color but I need to do this programmatically.

Here is my code

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
        //The issue is here
        CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(holder.checkbox, ColorStateList.valueOf(this.currentThemeOptions.modalFormsTextColor));
    } else {
        //This works just fine
        holder.checkbox.setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(this.currentThemeOptions.modalFormsTextColor));
    }
```

What do you suggest about changing border color of a checkbox in an Android API **lower than API 21** ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33834496/2299040

Comment: @SahilManchanda I need to accomplish this programmatically.

Comment: Make your chechbox  support checkbox android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox

Comment: Thank you @Bek. It worked for APIs < 21

Comment: @Emre rica ederim

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I've used for apps before that have a customizable UI:

```
AppCompatCheckBox box = new AppCompatCheckBox(activity);
box.setText("Checkbox");
ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                    new int[][] {
                            new int[] { -android.R.attr.state_checked }, // unchecked border color
                            new int[] {  android.R.attr.state_checked }  // checked color
                    },
                    new int[] {
                            Color.BLACK,
                            Color.WHITE
                    }
            );
box.setSupportButtonTintList(colorStateList);
box.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```