# Check upper case,lower case, length and symbols on text change edittext

Tags: android, regex, android-layout, android-edittext

I have four `checkboxes` which will be checked if condition satisfies in text change of `edit text`. One check box for uppercase, one for length, one for lower case and one for symbol. **once user starts to type one of these or all or all possible one needs to be checked.**

I have tried :

```
 mBinding.cetPassword.getEditText().addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    if (validateUpperCase(mBinding.cetPassword.getEditText().getText().toString().trim())) {
                        mBinding.chkUpperCase.setChecked(true);
                    }else {
                        mBinding.chkUpperCase.setChecked(false);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });

  public boolean validateUpperCase(String name) {
        Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]*)");
        Matcher ms = ps.matcher(name);
        return ms.matches();
    }
```

It does not works perfectly. on adding second upper case checkbox gets unchecked.

Please suggest! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check password using this methods:

```
private static boolean hasLength(CharSequence data) {
return String.valueOf(data).length() >= 8;
}

private static boolean hasSymbol(CharSequence data) {
String password = String.valueOf(data);
return !password.matches("[A-Za-z0-9 ]*");
}

private static boolean hasUpperCase(CharSequence data) {
String password = String.valueOf(data);
return !password.equals(password.toLowerCase());
}

private static boolean hasLowerCase(CharSequence data) {
String password = String.valueOf(data);
return !password.equals(password.toUpperCase());
}
```

then addTextChangedListener will be like this:

```
pass_word.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) 
{
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(pass_word.getText().toString().length() > 0){

                if(hasLength(pass_word.getText().toString())){
                    check_length.setChecked(true);
                }else{
                    check_length.setChecked(false);
                }

                if(hasSymbol(pass_word.getText().toString())){
                    check_symbol.setChecked(true);
                }else{
                    check_symbol.setChecked(false);
                }

                if(hasUpperCase(pass_word.getText().toString())){
                    check_upper.setChecked(true);
                }else{
                    check_upper.setChecked(false);
                }

                if(hasLowerCase(pass_word.getText().toString())){
                    check_lower.setChecked(true);
                }else{
                    check_lower.setChecked(false);
                }
            }else{
                check_lower.setChecked(false);
                check_upper.setChecked(false);
                check_length.setChecked(false);
                check_symbol.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey thanks! your code perfectly works for me. i have one querie regarding  hasSymbol method i want to check only some special characters in that. some specific characters. can you suggest for that?

Comment: if you want check only some special characters in hasSymbol, you can try to use:

private static boolean hasLength(CharSequence data) {
boolean check_some = data.contains("&") || data.contains("*"); //add what you want.
return check_some;
}

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you. One more question i want to ask off topic to this one. i want the check box with the custom drawable and font color. i have achieved custom drawable, but when it is unchecked color should be different and when selected color should be different. any tutorial or link for this?

Comment: please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854047/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-checkbox
or this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17647520/10408282

Comment: If you use the Pattern class, it requires that I use two backslashes "\\" before it will accept a hyphen. This is 2021 though, so this may have changed. Online java regex testers only use one backslash as well.

Answer (score 3):

don't use if-else used just if like below,

```
 if (validateUpperCase(mBinding.cetPassword.getEditText().getText().toString().trim())) 
      {    
          mBinding.chkUpperCase.setChecked(true);
      }
if (condition)   {
      mBinding.chkUpperCase.setChecked(false);
         }
```

Comment: how can if possible without condition?

Comment: it means just put condition in if statement. remove else .

Answer (score 2):

You need to use regex expression.
Code Here:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

  }

  @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    String lowerCase = "(.*[a-z].*)";
    String upperCase = "(.*[A-Z].*)";
    String digit = "(.*\\d.*)";
    String symbol = "(.*[:?!@#$%^&*()].*)";

    if(Pattern.matches(lowerCase,s.toString())){
      chkLowercase.setChecked(true);
    }else{
      chkLowercase.setChecked(false);
    }
    if(Pattern.matches(upperCase,s.toString())){
      chkUppercase.setChecked(true);
    }else{
      chkUppercase.setChecked(false);
    }
    if(Pattern.matches(digit,s.toString())){
      chkDigit.setChecked(true);
    }else{
      chkDigit.setChecked(false);
    }
    if(Pattern.matches(symbol,s.toString())){
      chkSymbol.setChecked(true);
    }else{
      chkSymbol.setChecked(false);
    }
  }

  @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

  }
});
```