# Changing color of Checkbox in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, checkbox, android-checkbox

It is possible to change color of CheckBox from react-native?
For now only when is checked color is Purple, but when is unchecked border color is gray.

```
<CheckBox
      value={isSelected}
      onValueChange={setSelection}
      style={styles.checkbox}
      labelColor={Colors.PurpleLight}
      color={Colors.PurpleLight}
      onPress={onPress}
      disabled={disabled}
    />
```

Thank u a lot :)

Comment: does this [similar stack overflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854047/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-checkbox) answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation @Manche you should use https://github.com/react-native-checkbox/react-native-checkbox , community checbox

And there you have the power of customising colors

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I've tried with tintColor but doesn't work

Comment: also I used react native, not react-native-community/checkbox