# android checkbox alignment

Tags: android, checkbox

[image]

this image show the default implementation of check box in android.

In this image check box is centre to the text. I want it to the top. what should i do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037795/android-spacing-between-checkbox-and-text Try applying that to your needs

Comment: this is somewhat different what i want.

Comment: Okay. Just wondered if you could apply that technique to set bottom or top padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used Relative layout. In  `<TextView>` i used the following code for top padding and my problem gets solved. :)

```
android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a custom 9-patch checkbox button with the stretchable portion defined at the bottom.. so the actual checkbox will be at the top and the rest space will be filled with transparency

Comment: it is working. Only small problem is checkbox text's gravity changing with it too.

Comment: @GökhanBarışAker Dont set the gravity. Have a custom 9-patch checkbox button with the stretchable portion defined at the bottom..so the actual checkbox will be at the top and the rest space will be filled with transparency..