# Is that is a bug with CheckBox in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox

I am using 2.1 android version. I was creating a check box and I saw something Strange with checkbox. When I put `android:padding="5dp"` the check box shown as

[image]

But the text should be shown next to checkbox. When I remove padding Its looks fine. Is that mean it is a bug or I am taking it in a wrong sense?

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Select the checkbox"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

Comment: what about if you remove the marginLeft?

Comment: Just again test after removing "android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" but result is same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's more of a bad implementation on Google's part. The answer to this question will have your solution: [Android - Spacing between CheckBox and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037795/android-spacing-between-checkbox-and-text)

Comment: Thanks , I read that link in details and got my pint. It's really bad as Google leave such a unexpected behaviors for us.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
android:layout_gravity="left"
```

you can try

```
android:gravity="center"
```

It did the work for me.