# Custom Checkbox Shows Different layouts for 2.3 and 4.2

Tags: android, layout, checkbox

I am Working on Project with inside i want to Use custome image for Checkbox checked/unchecked event.

inside my login xml i have write :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk_remember_me"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_uncheked"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Remember Me"
            android:textColor="#024d94"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here i have Used  `android:paddingLeft="5dp"` for getting space between button and textview.

**My Problem :** i got two different views for 2.3 and 4.2

> for  Device that has xhdpi or below density or that has large screen i
>   am getting below screen (this one is perfect as i want ):

[image]

> for  Device that has hdpi or below density or that has normal/small
>   screen i am getting below screen :

[image]

Can anyone tellme where am i missing? or anything Wrong in my layout?

I want the same layout screen which i am getting for 4.2 device in normal/large screen devices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using a TextView to show the text?

Comment: @dmon: Thnks for your quick response. but i have tried your suggestion not able to solve my issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that `Checkbox` already uses padding by default internally and overriding it with `paddingLeft` causes these issues. You should remove that property from your XML.

If you still want to adjust the padding, you will have to do so programatically. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4038195/832776

To only apply it to >4.2 you can use the following, though I would test on emulators to make sure this issue isn't merely a problem with just *your* devices.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
```

Comment: Thnk you very much for your support. but by removing paddingLeft i am getting default space inside 2.3 which is very much more than i want. and for 4.2 i am not getting any space between button and text. so by removing paddingLeft do not make my problem solve.

Comment: @Bhavesh use 2 different layout, one for 2.3, and other one for 4.2

Comment: @chengbo: hehe!!..thnks but it is not the solution i want. there should be a way to work around for this issue.

Comment: @OlegVaskevich: Thnks. i tried it out your Suggestion with link http://stackoverflow.com/a/4038195/832776  but getting not perfectly solve my problem works perfectly in 4.2 but getting much more space between button and textview for 2.3 devices.

Comment: Honestly this sounds like a manufacturer customization that didn't work too well; after all, you'd expect that checkboxes should look fine by default.

Answer (score 0):

Give the fixed width to check box hopefully this can resolved your problem.

Comment: Thnks for your support. but tried it out your suggestion not able to solve my problem.

Comment: Tested. As expected, this adds padding to the entire control, not in between the checkbox and the text

Answer (score 0):

Don't give padding, it comes by default with Checkbox.