# How to remove padding around Android CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox, margin, padding

I need to put check to the right hand top corner of my imageview. But when I do this I noticed a default margin around my checkbox. Is there a way to remove this??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbImage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="132dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_background"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could use a negative margin.

```
android:layout_marginTop = "-5dp"
android:layout_marginRight = "-5dp"
```

Comment: Be aware, that your tests may fail, because espresso "won't see at least 90%" of the checkbox.

Comment: Any solutions for ConstraintLayout?

Comment: u can use android android:translationX="-5dp", but this is bad solution

Comment: Best answer . Thank you.

Comment: @BenitoBertoli I don't know what kind of person I am but this was still not the correct way back then. Please don't hide behind "answer is outdated"

Answer (score 182):

There's now a better way of doing this:

```
android:minWidth="0dp"
android:minHeight="0dp"
```

Comment: @Seza try using MaterialCheckBox from `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm really hoping that AndroidX will fix this issue

Comment: I think the answer is simple and good. It removed right padding in checkbox with no text.

Comment: For anyone doing this programmatically and having difficulties, try using `minimumHeight` and `minimumWidth` rather than `minWidth` and `minHeight`.

Comment: Works for `MaterialRadioButton`, `AppCompatRadioButton` and `RadioButton` since in this order they are subclasses of the latter

Answer (score 42):

To remove radio button default margins or padding in android

if you using xml

```
android:minWidth="0dp"
android:minHeight="0dp"
```

if using programmatically

```
 radiobtn.setMinimumHeight(0);
 radiobtn.setMinimumWidth(0);
```

Comment: thanks! this one is simplest and doesn't involve negative margins!

Comment: This is the only one that works in all cases as negative margins mentioned in other answers won't work with `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me in **Constraint Layout**. I hope it will work for another layout.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                ...
                android:translationX="-5dp"
                 />
```

Comment: Please don't post answers when it only "works" and you don't know the real consequences. This will have like thousands of complications in the long run

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/CompoundButton.java#500) for the CompoundButton class that is extended by the [Checkbox](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/CheckBox.java) class at the **onDraw()** method, the padding depends from the gravity

```
  @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        ...

            final int top;
            switch (verticalGravity) {
                case Gravity.BOTTOM:
                    top = getHeight() - drawableHeight;
                    break;
                case Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL:
                    top = (getHeight() - drawableHeight) / 2;
                    break;
                default:
                    top = 0;
            }
       ...
    }
```

So what you can do is set the xml value for the attribute gravity to
`android:gravity="top|start"`

But this can be used only if you don't want to use text with your checkbox, since the gravity is used to center the text.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @VladislavShcherbakov comment, it is:

```
android:paddingLeft="-5dp"
android:layout_marginStart="-5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
// android:translationX="-5dp"
```

Answer (score -4):

Why to complicate with a negative padding and all. Use the simple and straight way, give padding to the FrameLayout instead tof the top most Relative layout that would do the trick. As you have only the CheckBox in the second layout there is no need to give padding for it.

Please do let me know if you face any problems or have any further doubts

Comment: Just saying because in the issue what you need is not a padding but that there is some padding already that needs to be removed. This happens only in the older android version where the tick's tail goes beyond the checkbox