# How to apply custom image to checkbox in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to apply custom image to checkbox in android, for this I create an `check_custom.xml` file in which I define custom image for different states of check box like:

```
<item android:state_checked="true" 
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on" /> <!-- checked --> 
<item android:state_checked="false" 
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off" /> <!-- unchecked --> 
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_onfocus" />    <!--on focus--> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off" /> <!-- default -->
```

Three different images on three states on checked,on focus and on unchecked,
and then I assign this xml file to background attribute of check boxes,but I'm not getting required result, this technique apply the custom image as well as default image both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom checkbox image android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965484/custom-checkbox-image-android)

Answer (score 102):

Salman, set `android:button` instead of `android:background`.   See also [Custom checkbox image android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965484/custom-checkbox-image-android)

Comment: welcome.  If this worked I'd appreciate a click on the checkbox to the left, which helps an answerer's rep :)

Comment: It's cool and simple dude y don't he mark this as answer. i am +1 this

Comment: Nice, Saved me time :)

Comment: +1 Very nice touch and answer man. Thank you for sharing it with us.

Comment: Legend spotted. Thank mate.

Answer (score 22):

I didn´t like the appearance of the checkbox default image when the background layout was dark, so I changed it using a xml selector in order to have a white background in the button.

The selector is needed in android:button="@drawable/selector_check"

```
                 <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:text="Show password"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:button="@drawable/selector_check"
                            >
```

And the following is the content of "drawable/selector_check.xml":

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
          <item android:state_checked="true" 
              android:drawable="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background" /> <!-- checked --> 
          <item android:state_checked="false" 
             android:drawable="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background" /> <!-- unchecked-->
          </selector>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Copy the btn_check.xml from android-sdk/platforms/android-#/data/res/drawable to your project's drawable folder and change the 'on' and 'off' image states to your custom images.

Then your xml will just need `android:button="@drawable/btn_check"`

```
<CheckBox
    android:button="@drawable/btn_check"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true" />
```

If you want to use different default **android** icons, you can use `android:button="@android:drawable/..."`

Answer (score 4):

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ON" android:state_checked="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/OFF" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ON"/>
```