# android:tick coming out of checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox

[image]I am making an app in Samsung galaxy s and in my app i have to use check box and while using check box , the tick means the check appears out of box .Can anyone help me how to resolve this.
Thanks.

Comment: This is default behavior depending on your OS.

Comment: you are using in xml or dynamically

Comment: Adil, can i do anything to solve this

Comment: Can you share code for your layout (xml)?

Comment: @user775: it will need customization of `CheckBox`. you will find discussions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3965484/593709),  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5177172/593709) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3569412/593709)

Comment: Post layout xml code, and with the snap. Because 1 snap = 1000 words

Comment: <CheckBox
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                               android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                               android:gravity="fill" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is native behaviour of galaxy s , checked come out of box .If u try it on other device it will work fine.So donot worry , its not your fault , its native behaviour of phone

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the custom checkbox.Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177172/how-to-apply-custom-image-to-checkbox-in-android) where u can get the idea about it....