# Make a tick togglebutton android

Tags: android, android-imageview, togglebutton

> Is it possible to have a tick `togglebutton` ?

The layout is below

[image]

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/donePic"
            android:src="@mipmap/done"
            android:tint="@color/red"
            android:paddingLeft="320dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Currently the tick `button` is `ImageView`. How to make the `ImageView` become `toggleButton` ? Is it possible ?

Comment: `Make a tick togglebutton` ... Why not a `CheckBox`, instead? i.e.: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_checkbox_control.htm

Comment: @Rotwang thanks for your suggestion, will try it.

Comment: Well, it's ready-made just out of the box, so no need to reinvent the wheel.. ;)

Comment: But if I want to have a tick toggle button (as image above), red untick, green when tick. Is it possible to have it ?

Comment: Sure, just customize your CheckBox button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177172/how-to-apply-custom-image-to-checkbox-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a Tic  toggle button with selector

```
<ToggleButton 
                android:id="@+id/toggle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/check"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn="" />
```

**Selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use tic -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tic_img"
          android:state_checked="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use un tic-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/untic_img"
        android:state_checked="false"/>

 </selector>
```

Comment: what if I want to make it become red when untick, and tick become red?

Comment: sorry i do not get you can you please elaborate?

Comment: where should I put the Selector ?

Comment: In the drawable folder dear

Comment: Need  `android:background="@drawable/check"` ? How does the Selector get called ?

Comment: My Dear for that you have to read android DOC because this is the primary concept of selectors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124536/discussion-between-john-and-mohit-trivedi).

Answer (score 0):

Set up onClickListenr for your imageView and when the user click the image, change the drawable to done or to undone.

You can keep a boolean value to see whether the user has clicked `boolean ifClick = false` or not!

Answer (score 0):

You can use two images,one for toggle off and another for toggle on and set onClickListner on imageView.

```
boolean isToggle=false;

yourImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(!isToggle)
                {
                    //Do whatever you want to do

                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.toggleOffImage);//set Toggle Off image
                    isToggle =true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Do whatever you want to do
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.toggleOnImage); //set Toggle Off image
                    isToggle =false;
                }
            }
        });
```