# how to set the color of checkeditem box of listview to other color other than green on clicking a particular item in listview?

Tags: android, listview

i have a listview.when the user selects a particular item the checkbox color turns green...I want that the color of the checkbox should turn orange or red..how is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom checkbox image android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965484/custom-checkbox-image-android) Also please choose a shorter title on the next question. Two lines is way too much, the question body is meant to be used for further descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

```
<CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:text="new checkbox"
 android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" 
 android:button="@drawable/checkbox" />
```

The @drawable/checkbox will be as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on_background_focus_red" />
 <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off_background_focus_orange" />
 <item android:state_checked="false"
  android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off_background" />
 <item android:state_checked="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on_background" />
</selector>
```

checkbox_on_background_focus_red, checkbox_off_background_focus_orang, checkbox_off_background and checkbox_on_background are the your desired checkbox images from your drawble folder

Answer (score 0):

```
1- implement the OncheckedLinstener and notify data set changed to list 
2- put check in getview if(chk.isChecked()){//setBG color green }else {red} 
2- either set the selector to checkbox or change the BG color of chk box in if else in getview
```

if want's to optimize then

set the position of the list item with check box in tag and in OncheckedLinstener you 'll get the view just get the position from view from tab and using getFirstVisiblePosition and getLastVisiblePosition, getChildAt(int index) and change it.

Comment: can you tell me how to set green or red color..i have no idea how to do it? can u tel how to change the BG color of chk box ?

Comment: are you using custom adapter ?

Comment: then simply change the color of linear layout which you inflated in getview......

Comment: no i am not using custom adapter.actually my listview is generated at run time

Comment: which adapter you are using ?

Comment: i cannot post my answer.but if u got any hint of what i am trying to say.please comment

Comment: if you are using  simple_list_item_multiple_choice layout in adapter then  onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) { you can use view.setBackgroundColor(Color.Green); but you need to get the chkbox child to get state and get it using CheckedTextView chk = (CheckedTextView)findViewbyId(adnroid.R.id.text1);  if(null!=chk&& chk.ischedk()){view.setBackgroundColor(Color.Green);}