# How to make a checkbox look better in android

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox

This is my XML for my check box:

```
<CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/atm_checkbox"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="@color/input_color" />
```

And it looks like this:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/528/47342915.png/

This is what i found on internet:

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkAndroid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/chk_android"
        android:checked="true" />
```

which looks like [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-checkbox-example/)

how to change my checkbox to look like the one i found on internet.
As my rep is <10 i cant upload image of my checkbox, or can anyone help me how to style checkbox to make it look better

I think both the xmls have similar code, but why are they looking so different?

Comment: Upload into some image services and give us the link.

Comment: Please share the link of images: how your checkbox look like now and how do you want to display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want custom the look of checkbox see this [tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_change_look_of_checkbox-t4553.html) and find everything.

By the way, the `checkbox` from your link is for Android3.0 and above.

Comment: by "your link" you mean what i am currently getting?

Comment: Your tutorial link. You want your checkbox like that?

Comment: yeah i want like that, i am using 2.3 so this is all i can get?? :(

Comment: So you can follow my link. Find checkbox style in android3.0 folder and apply to your checkbox. That tutorial is so clear

Comment: but in the link which i posted in the question says "P.S This project is developed in Eclipse 3.7, and tested with Android 2.3.3."

Comment: Did you read my link? Checkbox appearance not depent on Android version. It's just image+ selector. You can find the resource in android3.0 and copy to your project.

Comment: i could solve my problem by changing the width and height to wrap content, don't know how this mattered

Comment: AFAIK, checkbox and radio button has fixed size so if you specify height and width, it makes your checkbox is clipped. So that my tutorial link is useful for anyone who want to customize.

Answer (score 0):

CheckBox derive from Button class, so you can set a background image like button. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965796/818587), may be it is what you are looking for.

Comment: using the code in the link given (adding image), gave me a similar checkbox, but instead of a square there is a start now, which is not visible 100%, some 10% of it is cut to the right, is this because i am not using width = "wrap content" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a clean design without codes, use:

```
<CheckBox
   android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:drawableLeft="@android:color/transparent"
   android:drawablePadding="10dp"
   android:text="CheckBox"/>
```

The trick is to set colour to transparent for `android:drawableLeft` and assign a value for `android:drawablePadding`. Also, transparency allows you to use this technique on any background colour without the side effect - like colour mismatch.