# ListActivity with a complex row item: how to access row views?

Tags: android

I'm pretty sure this is possible, but oddly enough can't find how.
So, I have a `ListActivity`. I want this to be its row element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        style="@style/CheckBox" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        style="@style/Label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I can already use this layout, I know how to specify `TextView`'s id when creating `ArrayAdapter`. The layout is inflated fine, I can tick the checkboxes.

The problem is, I don't understand how to access those checkboxes. I need an inflated row layout to call `findViewById` on, but it's inflated asynchronously, not immediately when I add items to adapter. How to do this?

Comment: This is same as TestView.. what is the problem. explain

Comment: And what you want to do with them?

Comment: @PankajKumar: it's not the same. I do: `ArrayAdapter<String> list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.text, items);` and it fills `TextViews` on its own. I don't have to do it manually. `CheckBoxes` I need to access myself, and it's unclear how.

Comment: @Geralt: When a new list row is added, I need to get a reference to its `CheckBox` (possibly asynchronously, I don't care). For example, if I could just get the row view, I would call `findViewById(R.id.checkbox)` on it and be done.

Comment: @PankajKumar All deepends what you want to do with Checkboxes. There are approaches i have now in my mind but don't seem efficient. If you would tell me what you want to achieve, maybe answer will come soon.

Comment: Check my answer here. I had the same question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16569700/1739882

Comment: @Geralt: When a CheckBox is checked, I need to uncheck all other checkboxes and store the index of a checked one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [delete multiple items in custom listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009209/delete-multiple-items-in-custom-listview)

Comment: @VioletGiraffe working on solution, be patient.

Comment: @Geralt: Thank you! I'm looking at the _shree202_'s answer and I think I can make it work for my task, but it's not going to be pretty.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Check it out man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a CheckBox is checked, I need to uncheck all other checkboxes and
>   store the index of a checked one

Here is my solution that came into my head right now. I don't now your implementation (implementation of Adapter, source of data etc.) so you will maybe need a little modifications. So now to my solution:

You need [onCheckedChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) and put in into your **ListAdapter** class:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
   // do your stuff
}
```

Now i don't know your actual scenario but most likely you have some collection of objects you are passing into Adapter and you're using it in **getView()** method that returns view of row.

Exactly here i suggest to modify your Object (item that represents each row in adapter) and add property:

```
private boolean isChecked;
```

*that will "represent" your CheckBox*.

Now implicitly each **CheckBox** will be unchecked (it's ok since booleans are implicitly assigned into false).

And now directly into Adapter class. In your class, exactly in your **getView()** you need to do following:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   RowHolder holder = null; // RowHolder that holds widgets for each row
   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); // for inflate rows

   // logic for inflating rows, pretty simply
   if (convertView == null) {
      // inflate row
      convertView = inflater.inflate(<yourLayout>, null, false);
      holder = new RowHolder(convertView);
      convertView.setTag(holder);
   }
   else {
      // recycle row
      holder = (RowHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }

   // inicialising row values
   final Item i = collection.get(position); // item from collection

   /** here will be work with CheckBoxes **/

   // here you will set position as CheckBox's tag
   holder.getCheckBox().setTag(position);

   // set CheckBox checked or not due to item in collection
   holder.getCheckBox().setChecked(item.isChecked());

   // and assign listener to CheckBox
   holder.getCheckBox().setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}
```

This is very immportant logic. Here you saved position of **CheckBox** in Adapter into CheckBox itself. Now CheckBox knows *"where is located"*.

And then your listener will make following:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
   // buttonView is CheckBox you changed state so we know which CheckBox it is
   int position = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();

   // if CheckBox is checked
   if (isChecked) {

      // iterate collection and assign all items except selected into false
      for (int i = 0; i < collection.size(); i++) {
         if (i != position) {
            collection.get(i).setChecked(false);
         }
      }

      // now call notifyDataSetChanged() that will call getView() method again
      // and it will update your List
      notifyDataSetChanged();
   }  
}
```

Here listener will make a trick. Also there is something about

- [Holder design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289812/findviewbyid-vs-view-holder-pattern-in-listview-adapter/19289890#19289890)
- [Android Custom ListView with Image and Text](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

I hope it'll help you reach your goal.

Comment: Actually, I didn't even have a custom adapter up until now :)

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Custom Adapter is very efficient way how gain much more control over your Adapter.