# Issues designing Android UI in Xamarin

Tags: android, user-interface, xamarin

I am in the process of writing my first android app.  I figured, for a simple exercise, I'd write an app to keep score in bowling.

I want to create a picture of the pins, with a touch toggling a pin between standing, and fallen.  Then an ok button, that completes the shot. After each shot is entered, have a picture of the score updated.

Then, I want to be able to click on a frame, and edit it...mistakes happen.

This seemed simple enough.  At least if I were to whip up something in HTML5 I would be done by now.

However, I'm struggling with just drawing the UI...ugh.

Would I just create the pins as image buttons?  And how do I align them properly...I can't seem to drag stuff where I want, it's all left aligned and stacked.  Nothing like it should look.

And how can I dynamically create images for buttons?  At least that's how I was thinking I would do the score (showing all 10 frames with the shots and running score.

I realize this is a beginner question.  But I've been at it for five hours, and I'm no farther along.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's necessarily fair to compare your speed in a dev environment you are new to with one you already know - you are bound to be slower in the new one.

---

To get more familiar with android's XML layouts, I recommend you take a look through some of the tutorials on layouts - on linearlayout, gridlayout, relativelayout, etc which I think will have you quickly working in XML to generate your ui.

One such tutorial is http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/an-mono-for-android-wrappanelflowlayout.html

Once you've learnt a bit about the XML, I suspect you'll also find the designer easier too.

---

For the questions about the pins, well these sound a lot like checkboxes, only drawn differently - so check out:

- [Custom checkbox image android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965484/custom-checkbox-image-android)
- http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-custom-checkbox

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check them out.  And I realize I won't be as fast...but I was making **zero** progress. I have also ordered the book 'Professional Android Programming with Mono for Android and .NET/C#' which should help alot.

Comment: @CaffGeek : keep on reading the documentation and progress will be exponential in some time.