# Increasing the size of the check in Checkbox

Tags: java, android, xml, checkbox

I want to increase the size of the check in the checkbox.  I am thinking that I add an image for a new check.  But I don't see any options in XML to change the check for the checkbox.  Is there an XML option I am missing or a way to add the new check image to java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox" android:state_checked="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/checkboxselected" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox"/>
```

Add it to your check box in xml

```
 <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                **android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"**
                android:text="CheckBox"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the checkbox `Drawable` by setting `android:button` of the `CheckBox`.

See this answer for more information on how to create your `Drawable`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17647520/379245