# How to make customized checkbox in android?

Tags: android, android-checkbox

[image]

How can i make the checkbox as like the image in android. can anyone help me?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Also, who upvoted this? This is far too broad.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965484/custom-checkbox-image-android

try this~

Comment: YOU need to show what you tried first!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** In you `res/drawable` folder, create `"custom_checkbox.xml"`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cbox" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cbox_selected" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cbox"/>    
</selector>
```

**Second:** In you `res/drawable-hdpi` folder, paste two files named "cbox.png(which is unselected image of checkbox) and cbox_selected.png(which is selected Image of checkbox)"

**Third:** Now in you checkbox declaration

```
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox" />
```