# Android custom checkbox (or ToggleButton) with numbers inside

Tags: android, checkbox, togglebutton

I'm writing an app that will have 60 checkboxes, numbered 1-60. 
My goal is to achieve something like this:

[image: Unchecked]   [image]

Is there a way to achieve this without having to draw 60 .png files with the number inside? Could I draw only the edges and add the numbers as a text property of the button?

I tried customizing a ToggleButton (got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32964989/660711))

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/toggle_selector"
    android:background="@null"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textOn="60"
    android:textOff="60" />
```

**toogle_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/not_checked" />
</selector>
```

but as a result, the text was placed at the right of the button. Is it possible to place the text on top of the image?

Comment: Maybe remove the "paddingLeft" item?

Comment: @Christine, just tried, but didn't make any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with relative layout with textview on top of Toggle button like this. Replace margins and size as per your need

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_floating_material_dark"
    tools:context="com.contag.app.fragment.NavDrawerFragment">
    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/toggle_selector"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textOn="@null"
        android:textOff="@null"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="156dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="60"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Looks like this]