# Android: Check box selector not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, android-checkbox, android-selector

I am developing an application in which i am using check box and applied selector on that. My code of **check box** is as follows :

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

**custom_checkbox.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_unchecked"/>

</selector>
```

**checkbox_checked**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:drawable="@drawable/green_tic"/>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius_for_ask_option"/>
            <size
                android:height="20dp"
                android:width="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**checkbox_unchecked**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="2px"
                android:color="@color/color_light_grey" />

            <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius_for_ask_option" />

            <size
                android:height="20dp"
                android:width="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

The above code is working fine on Note 3 and same kind of phone. It looks like :

[image: uncheck][image: checked]

But on samsung s2 it looks like :

[image: uncheck][image: checked]

Comment: Looks like this is [common trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965484/custom-checkbox-image-android). `android:button` and `android:drawable` seem to be the candidates. What happens if you change to `android:drawable=`?

Comment: actually checkbox's default color varies from device to device. And also try adding checked false attribute with your unchecked item line

Comment: I had to use `app:useMaterialThemeColors="false"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a transparent solid to your shapes:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius_for_ask_option"/>
    <size
        android:height="20dp"
        android:width="20dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

Same for the other drawable XML.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this you should use  app:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox" instead of  android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).