# How to add radius to check box in Android

Tags: android, customization, android-checkbox

I have created a custom check box and a custom style for it. But when I add color or radius to the check box, it applies the color or radius to the text of the check box as well as to the box itself.

How can I add radius to the check box only and not to the text in my custom Java class (that extends CheckBox) or in the style?

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom drawable for `CheckBox` image like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17647520/6950238) answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox" 
          android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkboxselected" 
          android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox"/>    
</selector>
```

Make sure your checkbox is like this

```
android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/Black" />
```

or [that](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-a-custom-checkbox-in-your-android-app/) tutorial.

Comment: Adding custom drawable in the `android:button` did not work for me in Material Checkbox version `1.3.0` . I had to set `android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_selector` instead and also set `android:button="@null` . You can also add `android:drawablePadding` to make it look good.