# Programmatically implementing multiple button states instead of separate buttons

Tags: java, android

I have a start button that initiates audio recording, and a stop button that ends the process.

This is the java code of the start button:

```
    startbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //My code
        }
    });
```

This is the java code for the stop button:

```
    stopbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //My code
        }
    });
```

This is their respective XML layout if needed:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRecord"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:text="Start Recording" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:text="Stop Recording" />
```

So far i use "setEnabled(True)" or "false" to manage the app. Instead i need to merge these states in a single button so it can be "START/STOP" for a more simplistic UI... There are more buttons but i will fix them on my own hopefully, after learning the how to. Cheers!

PS: I typed "//My code" instead of the actual code in order to save space. I can provide my code if needed.

UPDATE: My logcat:

```
2019-02-27 13:17:29.634 8550-8550/com.android.greg.garec E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.greg.garec, PID: 8550
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaRecorder.stop()' on a null object reference
    at com.android.greg.garec.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:96)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12693)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26101)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: either u can overlay 2 buttons and manage its visibility and clickable property to achieve this. or on click change its behaviour according to the state of player

Comment: Use a single button and a boolean variable for the state of the button (initially: recording=false). When button is clicked, set recording=true and change image of the button and vice versa.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17647520/10695093 try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey if you want to add both actions in one button then its simple just use boolean flag for the state for example set flag ***isRecording=true*** if recording started and set ***isRecording=false*** when recording stop.
(Note: Set isRecording global key into the class)

```
 startbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     if(isRecording){
         stopRecording();
         isRecording=false;
         startbtn.settext("Start Recording")
       }else{
         startRecording();
         isRecording=true;
         startbtn.settext("Stop Recording")
       }

    }
});
```

Comment: `startbtn` and `commonBtn` is same.

Comment: yes he just mention that i only want a one button so that i mention that btn as commonBtn

Comment: This looks promising, i will test it tomorrow and i hope it works :D

Comment: @Gregory if you find this answer helpful then please mark as right and upvote it.

Comment: I haven't gotten around it yet to see if it works because i am facing some other problems i need to attend to. Don't worry, i never forget the people who helped me.

Comment: have you defined key isRecording key above class?

Comment: Yes "boolean isRecording = true; " in the outer scope of the main class to make it global. There is no syntax error but the app crashes when i press buttons. I test change the value of isRecording to false or true in different places. Sometimes the app might Start recording but crash once i press stop. I can edit the question and post the entire file if you want to check it out yourself.

Comment: There is no compilation error, it runs but crashes once i try to record.

Comment: but there is log into android studio logcat please check that log in that run time error display.

Comment: I posted the logcat.

Comment: that is android media player error compiler not found media player instance have you define media player global?

Comment: Something really strange happened. I defined isRecording as false instead of true, and it appears to be working. However my play/stop playing buttons don't work now while they work perfectly if i live start recording/stop recording buttons separate. It is truly bizarre.

Comment: Never mind brother i fixed it! in my previous code, the one i copied-pasted i had been using setEnabled(True) or false too much, that was the problem. Your answer works but isRecording has to be globally set on FALSE instead of true by definition. Thanks!

Comment: Gregory you are right we need to set the key to false by default sorry i forgot to mention that in my answer i apologize for that. and thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score -1):

use Custom Checkbox for Record and Stop.
and check if it is Checked or not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17647520/10695093 try this you will surely get proper result

Answer (score -1):

Use can use a single buttom with .setTag()

```
singleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 if(singleBtn.getTag().toString().equals("Stop")){
     stopRecording();
     startbtn.settext("Start Recording")
     singleBtn.setTag("Record");
   }else if(singleBtn.getTag().toString().equals("Record")){
     startRecording();
     startbtn.settext("Stop Recording")
     singleBtn.setTag("Stop");
   }

}
});
```