# Android checkbox size and alignment

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have a simple default checkbox in android app:

```
<CheckBox
         android:id="@+id/sklad"
         android:layout_below="@id/barcode_text"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/skladlabel"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:checked="true"
         android:layout_width="48dp"
         android:layout_height="48dp"
         />
```

However I have problems with alignment of the checkbox - as you can see, it is not centered in its view. I set the layout width to 48dp, because if I leave it as `wrap_content`, it says touch size too small.

So with this it looks good:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

But with 48dp width it looks like this:

[image]

So I just need to center it in its view and that way it will be closer to the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change CheckBox's button size (yes it is `button` property) by changing the layout's width and height. Maybe you can use `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties but they may not give you what you actually want.

Maybe you should consider using a custom checkbox.

See here:
[Custom checkbox image android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965484/custom-checkbox-image-android)

Comment: but if i use wrap_content, then there is no empty space next to the checkbox, and it fits very well. I just don't understand, when I use fixed width, why is an empty space on the right of the checkbox and not on the left. But i will consider custom checkbox if there is no solution for this

Comment: Actually, it doesn't add space next to the checkbox. It places the checkbox on top and start of the parent. If you set parent's width and height larger than 48. Such as 128dp, you will see that.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I solved it by adding negative margin. Not a proper solution, but it keeps the touch size 48dp and it is aligned next to the label `android:layout_marginRight="-18dp"`

Now the area is overlapping, but it doesn't really matter as the checkbox is selectable and touch size is kept. In preview:

[image]

In reality:

[image]