# Changing the color of the check in an xml checkbox

Tags: android

I am relatively new to working in xml, and I've struggled to make a checkbox that fits the theme I am looking for.

I attempted to use `android:buttonTint` as follows:

```
<CheckBox
       android:id="@+id/box1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:buttonTint="#115"
       android:checked="true"
       android:textColor="#eee"/>
```

but it colors the entire box, including the check mark. I would like to be able to change the color of the check separately, and I'm sure there's a way to do it, I just don't know it.

Comment: Provide your own custom drawable(s) for the `button` attribute. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965484/custom-checkbox-image-android